# IE treating String response from JAX-RS web service as a file

Tags: java, javascript, html, internet-explorer, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS web service that returns json string. I have created an html form to consume this service. 
`<form action="/webserviceUrl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="result_frame">`

result frame : 
`<iframe id="result_frame" name="result_frame" style="width: 50%; height: 100px;" ></iframe>`

When i submit this form the web service is called and the result (json string) is returned to the browser. All browsers are successfully parsing the result and displaying it in the result frame, except IE. In IE the returned json string is considered as a file and it prompts me to download that file. When i open that file I get the same json string that is the output of my web service. What can i do so that IE parse it the same way other browsers are doing??

Comment: What `content-type` are you returning as response to the client?

Comment: Its application/json....The web service is working perfectly fine...the problem is the way IE treats response from web service

Comment: Are you sending back a `Content-Disposition` header with your response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE always load the iFrame as a download file dialog.

Answer (score 1):

set `response.ContentType` to `application/json` and you should be through

Comment: I have used `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })` annotation for my web service method. I hope that is sufficient.